# Как поменять в середине массива два стоящих числа

Tags: c++, сортировка

Есть массив [0,7,1,4], нужно привести его к виду [0,1,7,4].
Я делаю бота так, что нужно чтобы это было не через ввод, а через сортировку.
Вот код:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n = 4;
  int random;
  int s = 0;
  int h[n];
  int t;
  int a[n];

  srand(time(NULL));
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (;;) {
      bool good = true;
      random = 0 + rand() % 9;
      for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        if (random == a[j]) {
          good = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (good) break;
    }
    a[i] = random; // присваивание рандомного числа элементу массива
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << a[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i += 2) {
    t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[i - 1];
    a[i - 1] = t;

  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << a[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: шта? сформулируйте вопрос более осмысленно

Comment: Нужно поменять по середине стоящие два числа местами, если конечно это возможно.

Comment: Размер массива известен? left ^= right; right ^=left; left ^=right

Comment: Размер массива равен 4

Comment: @ПрокопийБерезкин, так в чем проблема? Если размер заранее известен и константен? temp  = array[1]; array[1] = array[2]; array[2] = temp;

Comment: "...нужно чтобы это было не через ввод, а через сортировку." Ничего не понятно. Потрудитесь вменяемо сформулировать вопрос. Нужно поменять? Так поменяйте. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, вы просто хотите отсортировать 2 элемента массива.

Тогда это в C++ делается вот так:

```
sort(a+1,a+3);
```

Comment: Не хочет - 4 остаётся на последнем месте.

Comment: @Эникейщик А, я не понял. Надо сортировать не все...